# Cumulatively merge rows with the same index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

In python pandas, I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
> df
               count
date                
2021-04-03  23.0
2021-04-04  12.0
2021-04-04  10.0
2021-04-05  42.0
2021-04-06  39.0
...
```

Some of the dates are repeated, with a different count value. I would like to merge these values into one row like this:

```
> df
               count
date                
2021-04-03  23.0
2021-04-04  22.0
2021-04-05  42.0
2021-04-06  39.0
..
```

If it's any help the data source is a CSV file. There is likely a way to do this in a for loop but I was wondering if this can be done with a function in pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the index and sum the values in this case

```
>>> result = df.groupby(df.index)['count'].sum()
>>> result
date
2021-04-03    23.0
2021-04-04    22.0
2021-04-05    42.0
2021-04-06    39.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
new_df = df.groupby(['date']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen from your sample data, `date` should be the row index instead of a data column.  Therefore, you need extra step to convert the [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) result (a Pandas series) back to a dataframe by [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), as follows:

```
df.groupby('date')['count'].sum().to_frame(name='count')
```

Output:

```
            count
date             
2021-04-03   23.0
2021-04-04   22.0
2021-04-05   42.0
2021-04-06   39.0
```